# "Too many open files" exception while indexing data in elasticsearch using jdbc river

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, lucene

I was indexing all the records of a mysql table data(half million records) into elasticsearch using the [jdbc river](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc). Everything was going fine for sometime, and then suddenly the river started throwing some strange index error, whenever it tried to index a document.

Error:

```
    [2012-10-10 16:20:11,867][DEBUG][action.bulk] [Man-Wolf] [monitoring][0] failed to bulk item (index) index {[monitoring][mention_reports][70138], source[{"location":null,"wday":6,"monitoring_profile_id":22,"stream_type":"facebook","score":0,"tweet_count":0,"city":null,"to_user_id":0,"sentiment":-1,"post_message":null,"description":null,"location_data_source":null,"video_id":null,"year":2012,"post_name":"Danny Waddell's Photos","video_thumb_url":null,"user_follower":0,"tweet_text":null,"country":null,"content":null,"picture":"http://photos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/547714_507439249282865_1395188712_s.jpg","updated_at":"2012-08-04T16:06:59Z","model_id":82884,"month":8,"day":4,"profile_image_url":null,"result_type":null,"from_user_id":1407391780,"stream":null,"geo_coordinates_long":0.0,"tweet_id":0,"link":null,"state":null,"post_id":"1407391780_227741774015103","model_name":"FacebookSearchResult","id":70138,"title":null,"sub_location_1":null,"user_friends":0,"sub_location_2":null,"from_user":"Stephanie Morris","post_type":"photo","creation_time":"2012-08-04T16:05:20Z","created_at":"2012-08-04T16:06:59Z","to_user":null,"user_pic":"https://graph.facebook.com/1407391780/picture","video_type":"youtube","is_active":1,"caption":"obama will let them die for america  but  not vote","hour":16,"country_code":null,"duration":0,"positive_keyword":"obama","geo_coordinates_lat":0.0}]}
    org.elasticsearch.index.engine.IndexFailedEngineException: [monitoring][0] Index failed for [mention_reports#70138]
            at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.robin.RobinEngine.index(RobinEngine.java:482)
            at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.index(InternalIndexShard.java:323)
            at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:158)
            at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:529)
            at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:427)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/www/elasticsearch-0.19.0/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/monitoring/0/index/_1pr.tvd (Too many open files)
            at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
            at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
            at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.<init>(FSDirectory.java:441)
            at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.createOutput(FSDirectory.java:306)
            at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreDirectory.createOutput(Store.java:418)
            at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreDirectory.createOutput(Store.java:390)
            at org.apache.lucene.index.TermVectorsTermsWriter.initTermVectorsWriter(TermVectorsTermsWriter.java:123)
            at org.apache.lucene.index.TermVectorsTermsWriter.finishDocument(TermVectorsTermsWriter.java:143)
            at org.apache.lucene.index.TermVectorsTermsWriter$PerDoc.finish(TermVectorsTermsWriter.java:250)
            at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessorPerThread$PerDoc.finish(DocFieldProcessorPerThread.java:348)
            at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter$WaitQueue.writeDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:1404)
            at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter$WaitQueue.add(DocumentsWriter.java:1424)
            at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.finishDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:1043)
            at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:772)
            at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:2066)
            at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.robin.RobinEngine.innerIndex(RobinEngine.java:565)
            at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.robin.RobinEngine.index(RobinEngine.java:477)
            ... 7 more
```

JDBC River:

```
   curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/river_mention_reports/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/monitoring",
        "user" : "USERNAME",
        "password" : "PASSWORD",
        "sql" : "select * from mention_reports",
        "poll" : "2h",
        "versioning" : false
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "monitoring",
        "type" : "mention_reports",
        "bulk_size" : 200,
        "bulk_timeout" : "60s"
    }
}'
```

My mapping:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/monitoring/ -d '
{
  "settings":{
    "index":{
      "number_of_shards":5,
      "number_of_replicas":1
    },
    "analysis":{
      "filter":{
        "myCustomShingle":{
          "type":"shingle",
          "max_shingle_size":3,
          "output_unigrams":true
        },
        "myCustomStop":{
          "type":"stop",
          "stopwords":["a","about","abov ... ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer":{
        "myAnalyzer":{
          "type":"custom",
          "tokenizer":"standard",
          "filter":[
            "lowercase",
            "myCustomShingle",
            "stop",
            "myCustomStop"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings":{
    "mention_reports":{
      "_source":{
        "enabled":true
      },
      "_all":{
        "enabled":false
      },
      "index.query.default_field":"post_message",
      "properties":{
      "id":{
        "type":"string",
        "index":"not_analyzed",
        "include_in_all" : "false",
        "null_value" : "null"
      },
      "creation_time":{
        "type":"date"
      },
      "from_user":{
        "type":"string",
        "analyzer":"standard",
        "include_in_all":"false",
        "null_value":0
      },
      "from_user_id":{
        "type":"string",
        "index":"not_analyzed",
        "include_in_all":"false",
        "null_value":"null"
      },

            . . .


        "title":{
          "type":"string",
          "analyzer":"myAnalyzer",
          "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets",
          "null_value" : "null"
        }                                           

      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the most important part of the error message:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/www/elasticsearch-0.19.0/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/monitoring/0/index/_1pr.tvd (Too many open files)
```

Basically, your elasticsearch node is running out of file descriptors. See File Descriptors section of Elasticsearch [installation instructions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/_installation.html) for details on how to check how many handles are available to elasticsearch. In order to fix it, you need to increase the number of file descriptors available to the elasticsearch process.